# How can I write data from a table in a static block?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

How can I write data from a table xls in a static block? I need a context of activity for this, but I do not understand how to get it.

I'm using this code in the static block:

```
Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(/*there must be a context*/.getAssets().open("table.xls"));
```

Comment: Why? Static blocks are only executed when a class is first loaded, and you don't have much control over when that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I write data from a table xls in a static block?

You don't.

First, assets are read-only, so you never write to assets.

Second, you cannot use a static block for this, as you have no control over what thread will be used to execute that code.

And, third, you have no `Context`, and you will need one. Depending on circumstances, there may not *be* a `Context`.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way to initialize my array from the table only when I first start the activity?

Comment: @Tenday: Please do disk I/O on a background thread. Whether you (carefully) use an `AsyncTask`, or RxJava, or some other threading option, is up to you. When you start the activity, kick off the background I/O work, then use the results when they are ready.